# PNG image not uploading correctly to AWS S3 with Python and boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to create an endpoint that allows uploading a picture to my S3 bucket, everything seems to work correctly when uploading PNG images (JPEG images do not work but that's an issue for another time), however if I try to visualize the uploaded image in the browser it just shows as an black page with a little grey square in the middle. If I check the Metadata of the uploaded file, the Content-Type of S3 is correctly set to image/png, so I don't know what may be going on.

I pass the base64 image as multipart form-data and then decode it with

```
for part in multipart_data.parts:
    file = base64.b64encode(part.content).decode()
```

after that I use mimetypes guess_all_extensions() function to get the extension of the file. My uploading code looks like the following:

```
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
default_bucket = "some_bucket"
        try:
            s3_client.put_object(
                Body=file,
                Bucket=default_bucket,
                Key=file_key,
                ContentType=content_type
            )
       except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as error:
            print(f"error: {error}")
```

The image opened from the s3 management console looks like the folowing:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxfWc.png)

Comment: Did you check the developer console in your browser for error messages?

Comment: Yes, I don't get any error messages that I can see, I'm using serverless and the status of the request is 200. The image is correctly uploaded, it seems to be something about the format or something like that.

Comment: If you download the file via the AWS Console, that is, don't click on the link to open the image in browser, but instead click on the download button.  After downloading it to your local, can you open it with an image viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update! After many tries, I found out that I had to pass the `multipart.part` as the file on my put_object() function instead of the decoded base64 string. With that, everything is working as expected.

Comment: What is mulitpart_data here.  I am trying to upload an image from react, it gets saved but displays only black background